# How does the copy function work?

Tags: go, copy, slice

I don't understand how the `copy` function works based on the documentation:

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a
>   destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a
>   string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap. Copy
>   returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of
>   len(src) and len(dst).

```
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

Comment: What in particular?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The specification also covers the builtin functions `append()` and `copy()`: [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices). You should read it; it's quite clear.

Let's analyze the documentation of the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function and its uses with simple examples. You can try all the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/elXbEIkYJ8A).

Signature:

```
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

`copy()` is a function. It has two parameters, a destination and a source slice, whose element type is the same. It returns a number of type `int` which is the number of elements actually copied.

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice.

`copy()` will copy elements from the `src` slice into the `dst` slice.

```
src := []int{10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
dst := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

n := copy(dst, src)
fmt.Println("n =", n, "src =", src, "dst =", dst)
```

Output:

```
n = 5 src = [10 11 12 13 14] dst = [10 11 12 13 14]
```

It copied all five elements, and after the copy the destination has the same elements as the source.

Let's continue the example:

```
dst = []int{0, 1}

n = copy(dst, src)
fmt.Println("n =", n, "src =", src, "dst =", dst)
```

Output:

```
n = 2 src = [10 11 12 13 14] dst = [10 11]
```

Only two elements were copied because the destination only had two elements.

Continuing:

```
src = []int{10, 11}
dst = []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

n = copy(dst, src)
fmt.Println("n =", n, "src =", src, "dst =", dst)
```

Output:

```
n = 2 src = [10 11] dst = [10 11 2 3 4]
```

Again, only two elements were copied, but this time because the source had only two elements.

So `copy()` will only copy as many elements as the source or destination has, whichever is smaller. Or in other words, as many as the source "provides" or destination can "accommodate", whichever is smaller.

> (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a string to a slice of bytes.)

This means that the source can also be a `string` if the destination is a `[]byte`:

```
str := "Hello, World!"
data := make([]byte, 5)
n = copy(data, str)
fmt.Println("n =", n, "str =", str, "data =", data)
fmt.Printf("data as string: %s\n", data)
```

Output:

```
n = 5 str = Hello, World! data = [72 101 108 108 111]
data as string: Hello
```

This time the source was a `string` and `copy()` copied five bytes of the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) representation of the `string` (this is how Go stores strings in memory).

> The source and destination may overlap.

This means that `copy()` works correctly even if the destination is a slice which shares the same underlying array as the source slice, and the part of the array designated by source and destination has common parts (overlap).

For example:

```
copy(src, src[1:])
fmt.Println("n =", n, "src =", src)
```

Output:

```
n = 4 src = [1 2 3 4 4]
```

Here I specified `src[1:]` as the source, which is the source without the first element (this is a [reslicing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)). Since I excluded the first element, the source of `copy()` has four elements, so `4` elements were copied. The result is that elements were "shifted" to a 1-less index (therefore the first element being `0` is now gone from the slice), and the last element was not touched (because only four elements were copied).

> Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of len(src) and len(dst).

We've seen this in the above examples.

If you need to learn more about slices:

[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic example of how to use the built-in copy function:

```
// The source slice
source := []int{1, 2, 3,}

// The destination slice is where things will be copied to
destination := make([]int, len(source))

// The copy function returns a count of how many elements are
// copied from the source slice to the destination slice
copies := copy(destination, source)

// Some printing
fmt.Printf("copied %d elements\n", copies)  // Outputs: copied 3 elements
fmt.Println("destination slice:", destination) // Outputs: destination slice: [1 2 3]
```

[Example Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/E4dZ7Mz8Ey)

---

If the `destination` slice is of length `n`, and the `source` slice is of length `m`, and `n` < `m` the destination slice will be filled with the first `n` elements of the `source` slice:

```
source := []int{1, 2, 3,}
destination := make([]int, 1) // <-- Notice the 1
copies := copy(destination, source)
fmt.Printf("copied %d elements\n", copies)  // Outputs: copied 1 elements
fmt.Println("destination slice:", destination)  // Outputs: destination slice: [1]
```

[Example Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/b4lDlVv9G8)

---

A gotcha is that if you declare you destination slice as a slice literal like this:

```
destination := []int{}
```

The length will be 0 and nothing will be copied in.