# How is copy function implemented for slices in go?

Tags: go, slice

**I want to understand how go's copy function works for slices**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    arr := [10]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    copy(arr[4:], arr[2:])

    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

I was epecting the output to be **[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4]**

but it was **[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8]**

I want to know how it(i.e. copy) is implemented ??

Comment: Read [The Go Programming Language Specification: Appending to and copying slices](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices).

Comment: The _implementation_ is of no concern when you want to understand how it is working. This is the whole idea about "abstraction": You do not need to know how the internal guts are wired to understand the overall working.

Answer (score 2):

`copy` will copy `min(len(source), len(target))` bytes to the target. If the regions overlap, `copy` may work backward to avoid re-copying parts that are already copied. In your case, it would copy starting from the last element of the source going backward. In other cases, it may copy going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I think the things can help you

1. [How does the copy function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642907/how-does-the-copy-function-work)
2. copy()'s comments

```
// The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a
// destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a
// string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap. Copy
// returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of
// len(src) and len(dst).
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

In `copy(arr[4:], arr[2:])` case, src and dst are overlapped.

So, min (len(arr[4:]), len(arr[2:])) is 7.

The 7 elements which start from 2nd element (zero based index `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`) are copied to between 4th and 9th.

So the result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8]`

And if you are wondering its implementation, you can find runtime source directory's  memmove files which are written in Assembly. ([Golang's builtin function implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702934/golangs-builtin-function-implementations))

Comment: Don't know why such to the point and informative answer would be voted down.

Answer (score 0):

1. arr[2:]=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
2. arr[4:]=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
3. then copy function do: copy [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] into [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],so you get arr[4:]=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],and arr[:4]=[1, 2, 3, 4], so the result is arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8]